# Principles and methods of measuring the orbital angular momentum of $\rm H$-atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, hydrogen

When we talk about the orbital angular momentum (OAM) of the $\rm H$-atom, we mean the eigenvalues $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ of the OAM operator of the electron $\hat{L}^2$ defined from its classical counterpart ${\vec L}={\vec r}\times {\vec p}$ defined w.r.t the nucleus (the proton). The quantity $l$ is quantized. It can take non-negative integer values $l=0,1,2,3...$ etc.

I have two related questions regarding the measurement of OAM of H-atom (H-atom because it is the simplest bound system in atomic physics). First and foremost, how do we measure the OAM of the H-atom in experiments? Do we use well-defined photons as probes and use the principle of conservation of angular momentum?

Second, the definition of OAM is origin-dependent. The angular momentum of the H-atom is tacitly defined w.r.t the proton. Classically, a change of origin would certainly make a difference. Does this ambiguity survive in quantum mechanics? In other words, are the measured values of $l$ in quantum mechanics independent of this subtlety? Does the tacit choice of origin make no difference in $l$ values in quantum mechanics?